# In TypeScript why second overload of splice function is not found?

Tags: typescript

I have written the following code into TypeScript playground:

```
let x: number[] | number[][];
let y = x.splice(1, 1); // ERROR: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

For some reason, second overload of splice function, namely `splice(start: number, deleteCount: number, ...items: T[]): T[];` is not found and compiler reports an error.

However first version `splice(start: number): T[];` is found and it compiles just fine.

```
let x: number[] | number[][];
let y = x.splice(1); // OK
```

Why is it OK to call splice with one parameter while calling with two parameters is not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system can't tell that all of `(T | number)[] | (T | number)[][]` must be arrays, although I'm not sure why.

Changing your function declaration to:

```
function f<T>(
  input: (T | T[] | number | number[])[]
)
```

(indentation for clarity)

seems to solve it and is simpler, IMO.

Using the generic notation (`input: Array<Array<T | number> | T | number>`) also fixes the problem, despite all three being equivalent (I believe).

This might be something to ask about on the Typescript Github. I'm not sure why it's picking up one overload of `splice` but not the others.

Comment: The system can't tell that all of (T | number)[] | (T | number)[][] must be arrays - it seems to me it can, because splice `input.splice(1)` compiles fine, hence compiler knows that input is array. At least this is how I see it ))

Comment: @AlexanderNechay I'm trying to figure out just what type the compiler things `input` will be. It's something that will have a `splice` method, but not the usual `splice`s from `Array`.

Comment: TypeScript tutorial says: If we have a value that has a union type, we can only access members that are common to all types in the union. Here is the code which says different thing to as far as I can see: `let x1: number[];
let x2: number[][];
x1.splice(1, 1);
x2.splice(1, 1);
let x: number[] | number[][];
x.splice(1, 1); // Error`

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bug in the lib.d.ts definition for `splice` function: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11205.